# C#: public new string ToString() VS public override string ToString()

Tags: c#, oop

I want to redefine the ToString() function in one of my classes.

I wrote

```
public string ToString()
```

... and it's working fine. But ReSharper is telling me to change this to either

```
public new string ToString()
```

or

```
public override string ToString()
```

What's the difference? Why does C# requires something like this?

Comment: +1 for spelling your name the sensible way ;-p (and for it being a reasonable question...)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you use `public string ToString()` it is unclear what you **intended** to do. If you mean to change the behaviour of `ToString` via polymorphism, then `override`. You **could** add a `new ToString()`, but that would be silly. Don't do that!

The difference is what happens when you do:

```
MyType t = new MyType();
object o = t;
Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
```

If you `override`, both will output your new version. If you `new`, only the first will use your new version; the second will use the original implementation.

I don't think I've **ever** seen anybody use method hiding (aka `new`) on `ToString()`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have seen several examples of method hiding in C#.  None of them were pretty.

Comment: Oh sure, method hiding isn't *that* uncommon - I've just never seen it on ToString() ;-p But DbConnection.CreateCommand is a classic example in the wider context...

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. But I have a simple question In the case that the usage is very well controlled (never calling ToString() on the parent). Is the method hiding faster at run time? I want to say it should be!

Comment: @Niklaos I doubt it; and even if it is, it won't be by much - instance methods *always* use "callvirt", even for non-virtual methods. It *is* possible that the JIT optimises it, but...

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that ToString is a virtual method. In order to override a virtual method in C# you need to specify the override keyword.

You almost certainly do not want the "new" version.  .

Answer (score 4):

The [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(VS.71).aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) will hide or "shadow" the member with the same signature in the base class where as [overriding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3(VS.71).aspx) provides a new implementation of a member inherited from a base class.  Here is a [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172785.aspx) on the differences between shadowing and overriding.

Answer (score 2):

You want to override. There's really no advantage to hiding in your case (using "new").

Here's an article on [the differences between overriding and hiding](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html).

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't require it; Resharper does.  It requires it because the two keywords represent significantly different behavior, and if you don't specify, someone reading your code might not be entirely clear on which the default behavior is (it's `new`.)

In this case you clearly want to override.

Comment: Actually, even without R# you'll get a warning about this. The *language* doesn't demand it, but even the "express" (free) IDE knows it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

ToString is a virtual method in base class. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

What you do all depends on the behaviour you want. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302308.aspx#drguinet2_update_topic4) explains how the behaviour of ToString works depending on how you defined the method and what level in a class hierarchy you call ToString on.

Answer (score 0):

A personal recommendation from me would be to not use hiding; it causes many ambiguities and solves few.

Answer (score 0):

**ToString() method is available for every type in .NET**, as this method is defined as a virtual method in the base System.Object class, and all types directly or indirectly inherit from System.Object. If the default implementation of ToString() method doesn't server your purpose, you may wish to override (use override keyword) or hide (use new keyword) it.

I have come across the following 2 excellent articles explaining the reasons to override ToString() method, and the difference between method hiding and method overriding. There is also a youtube video on the same concepts
[Reason to override ToString()](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/07/part-57-c-tutorial-why-should-you.html)
[Difference between method hiding and method overriding](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/06/part-24-c-tutorial-difference-between.html)